# Hiding navigationbar with jquery .hover() hangs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im making a navigation bar that slides out from the left side of my website when you hover over the leftovers of the nav-bar. The catch is that when the animation runs and you hover your mouse back on the content section, it doesnt get registered and the nav-bar stays extended until you hover back and forth on the nav-bar once more. Does anyone know a solution for this?

```
    var hover = 0;                                  //navbar holder
var leave = 0;                                  //true if mouse left navbar

$("#navhover").hover(function(){

    hoverfunc(0,0,1,0,"+",1);
    $("#navhover").removeClass("navhovershow");
    $("#navhover").addClass("navhoverhide");

},function(){});

$("#content").hover(function(){

    hoverfunc(1,0,0,1500,"-",0);
    $("#navhover").removeClass("navhoverhide");
    $("#navhover").addClass("navhovershow");

},function(){});

function debugging(zeroone){
    $("#debugging").text(zeroone);
}

function hoverfunc(onleave,onhover,setleave,delay,addsub,numbah){
    if (leave == onleave && hover == onhover) {
        leave = setleave;
        hover = 1;
        debugging(numbah);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#navbar").animate({"left": addsub + "=170px"}, "300").queue(function(){
                hover = 0;
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
       },delay);
    }
};
```

Here you can see the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/cV3LU/
Any improvements on the code itself are also highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add a promise.

```
$("#navbar").animate({"left": addsub + "=170px"}, "300").queue(function(){
    hover = 0;
    $(this).dequeue();
});
$("#navbar").promise().done(function() {
   // check mouse location. collapse if out.
});
```

The promise will run as soon as the animation finished. Useful.

-- edited --

Easiest way to check mouse location is to add a mouse move function. Everytime the mouse moves you log the location into window.x and window.y

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    window.x = e.pageX;
    window.y = e.pageY;
});
```

Then, your current mouse location is always window.x. Check in promise.

```
    $("#navbar").promise().done(function() {
        if (window.x > 170) {
            alert("out");
        }    else {
            alert("in");
        }
    });
```

Comment: This might work, but ive no idea how to check if the mouse is currently on #navbar or #content.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:

```
function show() {
    $("#navbar").stop().animate({"left": "0px"}, "300");
    $("#navhover").removeClass("navhovershow");
    $("#navhover").addClass("navhoverhide");
}

function hide() {
    $("#navbar").stop().animate({"left": "-170px"}, "300");
    $("#navhover").removeClass("navhoverhide");
    $("#navhover").addClass("navhovershow");
}

$("#navhover").hover(show, hide);
```

The key is the call to `stop()`, which aborts whatever current animation is running if the mouse leaves the navigation bar while the animation is running.

You can see it working at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cV3LU/2/

Comment: that is correct, i want it to work like this. But if i add elements to the #navbar and hover over those, the navbar will slowly go left or right with the mouse blinking. Almost like it hovers-dehovers over and over again. I made the #navhover div because I didnt want the elements on #navbar to be selectable before the animation was complete.